# Android : why does native_start fails in startNavigating() on Android 2.3.1 emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, geolocation, gps

I am using Android 2.3.1 project to get a current location using LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.

This is my code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locListener = new BTILocationListener();

    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
}

public class BTILocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        Log.d("BTILocation", "Inside onLocationChanged() ---");

        if (loc != null) {
            double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
            double longitude = loc.getLongitude();

            String locationstr = "Latitude = " + latitude + " longitude = "  +longitude;

            Log.d("BTILocation", locationstr);



        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.w("BTILocation", "GPS is Disabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.w("BTILocation", "GPS is Enabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The permission set I use -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

I use open telnet connection

```
telnet localhost 5544
geo fix 12 22
```

I see following errors on logcat -

```
E/GpsLocationProvider(   75): native_start failed in startNavigating()
```

The location object returned in onLocationChanged(location loc) is always null on 2.3.1.

The same code works fine in Android 2.1 and 4.0. Please please help me solve this issue, I have tried google search but I couldn't find the solution anywhere. Thanks! I don't have Google APIs compatible with Android API level 7, does anyone know how I can download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's a known problem with platform 2.3 I downloaded Google APIs for platform 2.2 and 2.1 using android SDK manager. Just had to check obsolete checkbox to be able to download the required packages.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with 4.4.2 in API level 17. This is sporadic though, not really clear what fixes the issue. I did reboot of emulator, system all the usual stuff, nothing helped.

But I opened another emulator and that fixed them both.

Comment: More trouble - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/adt-dev/Z8NKJKyVmts